# Need for a regex

Tags: regex

I need a regex to get MyName ( MyName may contain any character except " ) from this string:

```
lablabla name="MyName" user="MyUser" lablabla
```

I used:

```
boost::regex reg(".*name=\"(?<action>.*)\"\\s.*", boost::regex::perl);
```

but it returns:

```
MyName" user="MyUser
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
boost::regex reg(".*name=\"(?<action>.*?)\"\\s.*", boost::regex::perl);
```

which makes it ungreedy; or:

```
boost::regex reg(".*name=\"(?<action>[^\"]*)\"\\s.*", boost::regex::perl);
```

which explicitly specifies that the action cannot contain double quotes.